# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo llamado "selection.php" en este debo hacer tres cosas diferente, en primer lugar se actualice el campo "oportunidad" de la tabla "nombre_tabla" que esta en "0", actualizarlo a "1".
En segundo lugar debo destruir la sesión y en tercer lugar debo mostrar los datos de la tabla "jugador"por medio de una consulta.
Estas dos ultimas cosas destruir la sesión y mostrar los datos de la consulta ya las hace el archivo el lio esta en la sentencia que tengo arriba para actualizar la tabla "nombre_tabla" la he puesto en todo el inicio del documento y me arroja error, también la he colocado por dentro del ifque tiene la variable de sesión pero en todas partes me da el mismo error. Mil gracias a los que me puedan ayudar.

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selection.php** on line **7**

```
$update = "UPDATE nombre_tabla SET oportunidad = 1 WHERE columna_usuario = $_SESSION['name']";
mysql_query($conexion,$update);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a almacenar la variable de sesión en otra variable que no necesite usar comillas:

```
$user = $_SESSION['name'];
$update = "UPDATE nombre_tabla SET oportunidad = 1 WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";
mysql_query($conexion,$update);
```

De esa manera no tendrás problemas con las comillas. De todas maneras, te recomiendo que uses [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para evitar problemas sobre todo de inyección SQL, ya que nunca se deberían usar parámetros recogidos de un usuario en una consulta SQL.

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado tal cual me distes el ejemplo y no muestra ningún error, tampoco actualiza la tabla.

Comment: Bueno, yo puedo revisar los errores que veo nada más! :) Prueba a debuggear la conexión a ver qué pasa. Puedes empezar por hacer `echo mysql_error()` a ver si hay algo ahí